# Get parent pages of current page in extension

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase

Is there a way to get all Parent IDs from a subpage via php?

```
...
Page
Page 12
    Subpage 21
    Subpage 22
        CurrentPage 23
```

Want to get 12,21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine` array.

it's indexed in natural order, which means, the 0 index is root page and last element is your current position.

So in your case it will be: `0=>12`, `1=>22`, `2=>23`

*Sorry initialy gave wrong description*

Comment: nice, that's what I'm looking for. ;)